# Function with specific conditions

Tags: functions

I have to find at least one function $f(x)$ that satisfies the following conditions (or prove that it does not exist):

1. $$f(x)<1\quad\text{for} \quad x\in \mathcal{R^+}$$
2. $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\quad \frac{1}{1-f(x)}=0$$
3. $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\quad f(x)=0$$

I always end with satisfying only 2 conditions over three.

Any suggestion on how to start?

Comment: Putting 3. into 2. I get $1$ as limit value, not $0$. Those conditions are not satisfiable at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove that such a function does not exist. $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0 =>\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{1-f(x)}=1 $$.